# Scroll view not able to handle linear layout

Tags: android, xml

The ScrollView is not able to hold the linear layout even when it is match parent or wrap content. why?
the code is below. the last couple of images are out of the screen. not only then but also when i add 5 more pair of pictures, the images are above the screen. i.e they cant be scrolled all the way. what could be the solution.
This code only includes 4 pair of images. the real code includes 10 pars of these. the images are way off. help would be appreciated.

p.s i tried to set the scrollview fillviewport to true but it didnt work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#82b1ff"
>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/pekkacard"
            android:src="@drawable/pekkacard"
            android:onClick="pekkacardclass"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="P.E.K.K.A"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:id="@+id/dragcard"
            android:src="@drawable/babydrag"
            android:onClick="babydcardclass"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Baby Dragon"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="170dp"
                    android:layout_height="170dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/golemcard"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:onClick="golemcardclass"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Golem"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="170dp"
                    android:layout_height="170dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/minipekkacard"
                    android:onClick="minipekkacardclass"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Mini P.E.K.K.A"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:src="@drawable/giantskelcard"
                android:onClick="giantskelcardclass"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Giant Skeleton"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="170dp"
                android:src="@drawable/skelarmy"
                android:onClick="skelarmycardclass"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Skeleton Army"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="170dp"
                    android:layout_height="170dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/wizardcard"
                    android:onClick="wizardcardclass"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Wizard"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="170dp"
                    android:layout_height="170dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/hogridercard"
                    android:onClick="hogridercardclass"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Hog Rider"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try to eleminate android:layout_gravity="center" in child of scroll view
and also remove xmlns from scroll view

Comment: it wont solve anything...

Comment: which theme you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#82b1ff"
    >
    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="170dp"
                        android:layout_height="170dp"
                        android:id="@+id/pekkacard"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_black"
                        android:onClick="pekkacardclass"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="P.E.K.K.A"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="170dp"
                        android:layout_height="170dp"
                        android:id="@+id/dragcard"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_black"
                        android:onClick="babydcardclass"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Baby Dragon"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="170dp"
                        android:layout_height="170dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_black"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:onClick="golemcardclass"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Golem"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="170dp"
                        android:layout_height="170dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_black"
                        android:onClick="minipekkacardclass"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Mini P.E.K.K.A"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="170dp"
                        android:layout_height="170dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_black"
                        android:onClick="giantskelcardclass"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Giant Skeleton"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="170dp"
                        android:layout_height="170dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_black"
                        android:onClick="skelarmycardclass"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Skeleton Army"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="170dp"
                        android:layout_height="170dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_black"
                        android:onClick="wizardcardclass"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Wizard"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="170dp"
                        android:layout_height="170dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_black"
                        android:onClick="hogridercardclass"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Hog Rider"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="170dp"
                        android:layout_height="170dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_black"
                        android:onClick="wizardcardclass"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Wizard"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="170dp"
                        android:layout_height="170dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_black"
                        android:onClick="hogridercardclass"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Hog Rider"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="170dp"
                        android:layout_height="170dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_black"
                        android:onClick="wizardcardclass"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Wizard"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="170dp"
                        android:layout_height="170dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_black"
                        android:onClick="hogridercardclass"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Hog Rider"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```